# save and upload data:image/jpeg;base64 string as a jpg file saying its too big

Tags: javascript, php

I have a page lets the user display a selected image to upload and it displays it in place to preview first                     . It reads it as readAsDataURL. I can save the data to a text string and can upload it with getJSON or AJAX but keep getting errors saying its too big of a string? I have tried to upload it as a file but then lose the functionality of pre viewing the image first.

I can resize the image and do what I need with it once uploaded in PHP but I can struggling to get any image over 5K to be accepted.

I have done a pen, https://codepen.io/julianchamberlain/pen/PoKLvqg

I have not used this before so i apologise if I have done something wrong or not explained it clear.

I am loading an displaying image like so:

```js
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $('#imagePreview').css('background-image', 'url('+e.target.result +')');
            $('#imagePreview').hide();
            $('#imagePreview').fadeIn(650);     
            $('#new_img').val(e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
$("#imageUpload").change(function() {
    readURL(this);
});

function saveimg(data) {
    
    var new_data={ 
    new_img : data.new_img
    };
    
    
    $.getJSON('upload.php', new_data);
    alert("uploaded");
```

```css
body {
  background: whitesmoke;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0 20px;
}
h1 small {
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  color: gray;
}
.avatar-upload {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 205px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.avatar-upload .avatar-edit {
  position: absolute;
  right: 12px;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 10px;
}
.avatar-upload .avatar-edit input {
  display: none;
}
.avatar-upload .avatar-edit input + label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: normal;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.avatar-upload .avatar-edit input + label:hover {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-color: #d6d6d6;
}
.avatar-upload .avatar-edit input + label:after {
  content: "\f040";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #757575;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}
.avatar-upload .avatar-preview {
  width: 192px;
  height: 192px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 6px solid #F8F8F8;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.avatar-upload .avatar-preview > div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/788cff4036.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
    <h1>jQuery Image Upload 
        <small>with preview</small>
    </h1>

    
    
    <div class="avatar-upload">
        <div class="avatar-edit">
            <input type='file' id="imageUpload" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" />
            <label for="imageUpload"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="avatar-preview">
            <div id="imagePreview" style="background-image: url(http://i.pravatar.cc/500?img=7);">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<input type='text' id='new_img' />
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="
var new_img = document.getElementById('new_img').value;
var data={new_img : new_img}; saveimg(data);
saveimg(data);">Save Image</button>
```

I am saving the data in a text input and adding a save button like:

```
<input type='text' id='new_img' />
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="
var new_img = document.getElementById('new_img').value;
var data={new_img : new_img}; saveimg(data);
saveimg(data);">Save Image</button>
```

and to send the data I am using this but I have also tried AJAX but get same or empty results.

```
function saveimg(data) {
    
    var new_data={ 
    new_img : data.new_img
    };
    
    $.getJSON('upload.php', new_data);
    alert("uploaded");
    
}
```

The upload php is :

```
$new_img = $_GET["new_img"];

$data = $new_img;
list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);

file_put_contents('img/operators/image.jpg', $data);

echo "done";
```

Comment: Are you transferring img data in a GET request? GET is limited use POST

Comment: I have tried using ajax but the file is empty? How do I use post using this method?  $.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php',
   data: new_data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data){
               alert("uploaded");
            }
        });

Comment: @JulesUK - Remove `contentType: false, processData: false` (you're not doing a standard file upload, you're just posting the contents as "normal" text) and then get it in your PHP with `$_POST['new_img']`

Comment: ? Using the AJAX? I have tried that and it send an empty file. Do you have an example of it please?

Comment: Thanks mate, I was forgetting to change to change GET to POST in the PHP, probably tried it before and didnt do it but thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Andreas,

I did it with a post instead like :

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php',
            data: new_data,                                                                                                  
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data){
               alert("UPLOADED");
            }
        });
```

Also changed the php file to POST instead of GET.